# Time between two button clicks

Tags: java, android, button, time

I´ve two buttons and I want to count the time between two clicks. I know how to do that once:

```
 Long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 Long differenz = ((endtime-starttime) / 1000);
```

Now, I want on the second click, that the count starts from zero again until the first button is clicked. Then, measure the time between first and second button click and so on.

Maybe it´s a really simple thing but I don´t know how to do...

**EDIT:** Ok, I try to make it clear:

I have Button A and B. I want the user to alternately push button A and B. When the user clicks on Button A, I want a timer to measure the time until B is clicked. Until here, everything is clear to me.
Now I want that the time between the click on B till the click to A is measured, always alternated between A and B.

I don´t know what to do after the click on B that the time is measured again until A.

Comment: Be more clear, name the buttons A and B and describe in detail what you want. For example what if A is clicked and click again....

Comment: what happen if A is clicked and clicked again? is it possible or do you disable A once it is clicked and only enable it again once B is clicked?

Comment: If A is clicked again, everything should stop. No, I don´t want to disable it!

Comment: What do you mean by should stop? start a new time?

Comment: A message should be shown that this was wrong. So the time is null again and the application stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class members

```
boolean mButtonAClicked;
boolean mButtonBClicked;

long mStartTime = 0;
```

When Button A is clicked

```
if (mButtonAClicked)
{
    // button A is clicked again, stop application
}
else
{
    mButtonAClicked = true;
    mButtonBClicked = false;
    if (mStartTime != 0) // Button B was clicked
    {
         Long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         Long differenz = ((endtime-starttime) / 1000);
         mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

When Button B is cliked

```
if (mButtonBClicked)
{
    // button B is clicked again, stop application
}
else
{
    mButtonBClicked = true;
    mButtonAClicked = false;
    if (mStartTime != 0) // Button A was clicked
    {
         Long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         Long differenz = ((endtime-starttime) / 1000);
         mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a field to hold last time each was pressed.

```
long aMillisPressed;
long bMillisPressed;
```

When Button A is clicked:

```
aMillisPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeElapsedSinceBPressed = aMillisPressed - bMillisPressed;
```

And when B is clicked:

```
bMillisPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeElapsedSinceAPressed = bMillisPressed - aMillisPressed;
```